# Show BottomNavigationView when selected tab is changed (hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior)

Tags: android

I have a BottomNavigationView and if scroll up it goes down in hide state. Now If I press back and previous fragment does not have any scroll, my BottomNavigationView  still hidden, Is there a way to force it to be visible?

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/my_nav_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you haven't figured it out yet, or if anyone else is having the same issue, this is how I managed to work around this:

Inside the activity that has the bottom navigation view and hosts the fragments, add the following method:

```
private fun forceShowNavBar() {
    if (my_nav_bar.translationY != 0f) {
        val layoutParams = my_nav_bar.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        val behavior = layoutParams.behavior as HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior

        behavior.onNestedScroll(main_container, bottom_navigation_view, frag_ct, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

If it's not clear what parameters you should have in `onNestedScroll`, you can read the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/behavior/HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior.html#onnestedscroll)

Then, override your `onBackPressed` method with the following:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        resetScreenState()
    }
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

It's important to call the method **before** `super.onBackPressed()`, otherwise the bottom nav bar won't be shown.